# How do I not include duplicate values in a React state array , how to prevent duplication of values in array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, duplicates, use-state, arrayofarrays

I want to store 15 different questions  in items[0].question state

I want to make sure that I can't push a duplicated value into an array in a React state. The duplicated value is still going in the array though.

I have tried using .includes but it is not working.

```
const [exam, setExam] = useState({
    subjectName: "",
    questions: [

    ], notes: [
        ""
    ]
})

const [item, setItem] = useState([
    {
        question: "",
        answer: "",
        options: []
    }
])

const nextQuestion = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const que = item[0].question

    exam?.questions?.push({ question: que, answer: value, options: [item[0].options[1], item[0].options[2], item[0].options[3], item[0].options[4]] })

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using setState, you will need to use `setExam` to update `exam`

Something like:

```
const newQuestion = { question: que, answer: value, options: [item[0].options[1], item[0].options[2], item[0].options[3], item[0].options[4]] }
newExams = {...exam, questions: [...exam.questions, newQuestion ]}
setExam(newExams)
```

Comment: this is done but I want to add the questions and options with no duplicate values, in this scenario duplicate values are also push

Comment: This will help you avoid adding duplicates to your questions list`if (exam?.questions.every(x=> !(x['que']== que))){
    //Answer
}`

Comment: And you can do something like this to remove duplicate options
`let options = [item[0].options[1], item[0].options[2], item[0].options[3], item[0].options[4]]
let optionsWithNoDuplicates = Object.keys(options.reduce((a,c) => ({...a,[c]: (a[c] || 0) + 1}),{}))
const newQuestion = { question: que, answer: value, options:  optionsWithNoDuplicates }`